# How to efficiently evaluate rows and sub records in single PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I'm struggling writing PL/SQL (I'm new to PL/SQL) and I'm not sure how to structure SQL and loops for something like this.

I have 128 lines of SQL to create something like the following cursor:

```
ID   Course   Grade Attend? Date
123  MATH091  B     Y       5/15
123  BIOL101  F     N       3/10
123  ENGL201  W     Y       1/2
456  MATH091  A     Y       5/16
456  CHEM101  C     Y       5/16
456  POLS301  NULL  NULL    NULL
```

With each ID, I need to several comparisons across the courses (e.g. which has the latest date, or were all courses attended). These comparisons need to be done in a certain order so that when they hit one that is true, they are flagged with a code and excluded from subsequent comparisons.

For example:

- All courses attended? If true, output as `attended` and remove from next steps.
- Find and store the latest date with a passing grade.
- Find and store the latest date with a non-passing grade.
- Is the later date after a course with a null grade? If true, output as `coming back` and remove from next steps.
- Etc.

Each condition can be easily written in a SQL, but I don't know/understand the appropriate structure to loop through this process.

Is there syntax that can accomplish this easily?

We're on Oracle 11g and we do not have permissions to write to a temporary table.

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand the question.  My guess is that you could simplify the SQL statement quite a bit using an analytic function or two.  But if you want to move from SQL to PL/SQL I'm not sure exactly what you're looking for.  You can obviously use a `for` loop in PL/SQL though I'm not sure what you'd be looping on.  You may want to build a pipelined table function to return the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you need PL/SQL for this. Except for the "unknown" requirement "etc." this can all be done in a single SQL statement:

Something like:

```
select id, course, grade, attended, attendance_date, 
       count(distinct case when attended = 'Y' then course end) over (partition by id) courses_attended,
       count(distinct course) over () as total_courses,
       case
          when count(distinct case when attended = 'Y' then course end) over (partition by id) = count(distinct course) over () then 'yes'
          else 'no'
       end as all_courses_attended,
       max(case when attended <> 'F' then attendance_date else null end) over (partition by id) as latest_passing_date,
       max(case when attended = 'F' then attendance_date else null end) over (partition by id) as latest_non_passing_date
from attendees
order by id;
```

Btw: the `attended` column is not necessary if you have an `attendance_date`. If that date is not NULL than obviously the student attended the course. Otherwise she/he didn't.

Of course I have no idea what the "etc." steps should do though....

SQLFiddle example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e7c95/1

Comment: I didn't realize that this level of logic was available just within SQL. This is exactly what I needed and this will be very handy for future SQL, too. Thank you very much!